# QR Code Security Testing

Tags: account-security, automated-testing, qr-code

Within the scope of a project for my client, I test the existing site and the project for security vulnerabilities using OWASP ZAP. The client uses invitations with QR Codes and QR Codes to login to his project.

How can I test QR Codes on security issues?

Can I also automate this process in the CI area?

Details to the QR Code:

- The QR Code of the customer contains a login number.
- The QR Code is currently only sent by mail.

https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/security-attacks-via-malicious-qr-codes/

Comment: Do you mean malicious QR code as in the QR code has something malicious about it and exploits the decoding software, or like the QR code has malicious content that attacks the web server?

Comment: QR Codes are just encoded text. You don't test the codes but what they do.

Comment: Exactly, suppose it would be possible to manipulate a QR Code in such a way that an unauthorized user could gain access to a page.

Comment: Can I even manipulate a QR Code in such a way that an unauthorized code is sent along?

Comment: So just SoapUI, or Postman is enough to make a query?  @schroeder

Comment: It depends entirely on the system you're using. You've provided no details. Imagine you replace QR code with a string of text. Start from there.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I test QR Codes on security issues?

The QR code is just a piece of data. It's no different from a bar code - or a text string.

It encodes data. Your question is essentially meaningless, as the QR code will not have security issues. The use of it, the distribution of it, or the content may have security issue.

So the real issue is:

- What does the QR code encode?
- How are they distributed?
- How are they used / read by the end users?

Except for the reading action (there *may* be security issues in the reader application), they're no different from a link in an e-mail or similar.